# how to assign a object that will be determined run in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I want ton assign the object dynamically based on the condition, i was not allowed to create variable without declaration.
var carSegment;

```
        switch (segmentType)
        {
            case "CarSeg":
                carSegment = new CarSeg();
                break;
            case "NonAirSeg":
                carSegment = new NonAirSeg();
                break;

        }
```

Comment: If `CarSeg` and `NonAirSeg` have any common ancestor, you can do `Ancestor carSegment;` before the switch statement

Comment: How would you expect to use the `carSegment` variable later on if you have no idea what type it is? This seems to me like a bad code smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this, both `CarSeg` and `NonAirSeg` need to share an interface or a base class, which would be the type for `carSegment`.  For example, if they both implement an interface called `ISegment`, then you could do this:

```
ISegment carSegment = null;
```

Then the assignments in your `switch` statement would work in their current state.  The same is true if they implement a common ancestor class.

The catch is that `carSegment` is that common type and only that common type.  If you need specifics to those two different types then you'd probably need to re-think your design outside the scope of this one code segment.